# Advantage of a 64k mtu for lo?

Tags: tcp, mtu

I saw [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=commitdiff;h=0cf833aefaa85bbfce3ff70485e5534e09254773) in the Linux kernel and was confused by it:

> loopback current mtu of 16436 bytes allows no more than 3 MSS TCP
>   segments per frame, or 48 Kbytes. Changing mtu to 64K allows TCP
>   stack to build large frames and significantly reduces stack overhead.
>
> Performance boost on bulk TCP transferts can be up to 30 %, partly
>   because we now have one ACK message for two 64KB segments, and a lower
>   probability of hitting /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_reordering default limit.

```
--- a/drivers/net/loopback.c
+++ b/drivers/net/loopback.c
static void loopback_setup(struct net_device *dev)
{
-       dev->mtu                = (16 * 1024) + 20 + 20 + 12;
+       dev->mtu                = 64 * 1024;
```

What does lo have to do with TCP transfers? Isn't it just a loopback address where you look ethernet traffic for whatever reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a change to the loopback interface, it's a performance boost for transfers *on the local interface*. Like if you FTP to 127.0.0.1, for example.

Comment: ... and **only** on the local interface!

Comment: Interestingly Windows 7 has an MTU on the lo of 4.3 billion bytes. Why not do something similar with the Linux kernel?